# What does it mean to % 2147483647L on epoch time?

Tags: java, push-notification, unix-timestamp, integer-overflow

I just stepped onto problem with generating id for notification in Android.

I'm going through some notification-handling-sdk and they are using this code to generate notification id:

```
private int generateTimestampId() {
    return (int)(new Date().getTime() % 2147483647L);
}
```

This is probably good solution, **but I can't understand what `% 2147483647L` stands for in context of epoch time**.

(please note: `new Date().getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51472673/7666442

Comment: FYI, `2147483647L` = [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), the limit of a 32-bit signed integer number.

Comment: ah, thanks @BasilBourque so this is just to limit epoch (which will - in general - not fit into int; "integer overflow" https://dzone.com/articles/overflow-and-underflow-data) to int

Comment: What class is `Date` here? The `getNow` method you called is not an [`java.util.Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date) class.

Comment: This code: `(int)( (new Date().getTime()) % 2_147_483_647L) ` when [run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/5rOhc4) returns `171515712` (171,515,712).

Comment: sorry @BasilBourque I made a mistake, there is no "getnow" - question edited

Comment: FYI, [`Date::getTime`]() returns a `long`, a 64-bit signed integer, representing the count of milliseconds since the epoch reference moment of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. I do not grasp their purpose in taking the modulo of that number by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Obviously they are trying some strategy to grab a 32-bit value as an identifier, but I do not understand the strategy. FYI, you cannot get  a suitable id from an arbitrary 32-bit number. When you need a universally unique identifier, use a [Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: Theoretically they're exposing themselves to duplicates after slightly less than 25 days.  Assuming 5K calls per day, that's 125,000 calls per 25-day cycle.  In the second cycle, the probability of one single call not overlapping with the entire set "used up" from the first cycle is 0,999941792.  The probability of all 125,000 calls from the second cycle not overlapping with any from the first is 0,0006918.  People underestimate the power of, eurhm, powers.

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question in bold : '%' stands for the modulo operator (remainder after division), 2,147,... is the highest possible 31-bit integer (32-bit with sign included) and the L suffix turns that number into a long instead of an int.

Comment: @ErwinSmout your not being funny :) the question is asked in certain context - not only the bold part is important. But I dont have to tell you that, do I? (anyway I edited the question)

Comment: OK.  It will yield the number of milliseconds passed since the last moment in time that is an exact multiple of 2,147,483,647 milliseconds after the epoch.  As a means to obtain a meaningless and mostly unpredictable number, it's a good idea.  Hoping no one will never ever "hit the same millesecond" is, eurhm, fairly optimistic.

Comment: @ErwinSmout "Theoretically they're exposing themselves to duplicates after slightly less than 25 days." I didn't state it clearly but this is a client (Android) code and it's a fallback only (when id does not come along with notification data itself - then client has to generate something meaningful). So overlapping is impossible. Sort of :P

Answer (score 1):

It could be done to prevent negative values which will happen when `long` is narrowed to `int`. Consider the following code:

```
long value = 1L + Integer.MAX_VALUE; // anything past max integer
int i1 = (int) value; // -2147483648
int i2 = (int) (value % 2147483647L); // 1
```

With the `% 2147483647L` the code ensures that the number will always be smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is 2147483647, before it will get narrowed to `int`.

It more or less makes sense in context of generated ids, we rarely use negative numbers for this use case.