# Android Notifications: which tag/id pairs to use to ensure all notifications are shown?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

In an app I get different messages from the backend, which I want to show as UI Android notifications.

But when I use the same notification ID, e.g. `123`, a new notification would update the old one. I want all notifications to show instead.

So there is a `tag: String` that we can use to assign an additional tag to a notification. But if I would use the same tag I would get the same behaviour as before: A new notification would update the old one, and not show up as a second notification.

So what's the right tag to use in this case? Here some variants:

```
val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)

// option 1: use some random tag
notificationManager.notify(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 123, notification)

// option 2: use toString as tag - but same data will not show notification twice
notificationManager.notify(someData.toString(), 123, notification)

// option 3: use hashCode as tag
notificationManager.notify(someData.hashCode().toString(), 123, notification)

// or something else?
```

For now I don't plan to cancel the notifications programatically - but it would be nice to have possibility to do so.

What's do you use as `tag` in notifications? How do you ensure all notifications are shown?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51472673/7666442

Comment: getActiveNotifications() then you can just do a plus 1 in id . the new notification will have new id

Comment: @NileshRathod Your solution uses a date as a notificationId, which is a similar approach to my option 1 (random).

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan I could do that, but then I would have to check all existing notifications every time I would show a new notification. I'm not so sure that is the way to go.